# Client Socket.io disconnects and reconnects to websocket persistently

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am connected via Socket.io 1.3.4 (via websockets) to the NodeJS server and client socket.io fires up "disconnect" event 5-30 seconds.

Every "disconnect"->"reconnecting"->"reconnect" iteration takes approx. 2 seconds. I am connected via cable to pretty stable network. Server is hosted on AWS.

Sometimes I have bad Wi-Fi connection, but no "disconnect" event fire up at all.

1. How can I debug this issue?
2. How can I see who is guilty - server or client?
3. How does socket.io understands that it is time to disconnect? Could not understand this from their code.

**Edit**. Socket.io config:

```
io = require('socket.io')(server, { 
      log: false
    , "close timeout": 60
    , "heartbeat timeout": 60
    , "heartbeat interval": 20
})
```

Comment: Do you use any load balancer on AWS? As for me nginx was interrupting websockets as well.

Comment: I use dotcloud as a cloud hosting. They definetly use. I will ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with nginx running in front of node, and it was because `proxy_read_timeout` and `proxy_send_timeout` were set too low. Socket.io sends heartbeats every 25 seconds, so make sure you set those timeouts to something greater than 25s.

Comment: Thanks for response. Please see my config (in the question, which value should I change?)

Comment: @igorpavlov If you can't change the nginx settings, you can try reducing socket.io heartbeat interval to 10 seconds, and the timeout to 30 seconds.

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: Shall I change both close timeout and heartbeat timeout to 30 seconds? Could you please provide recommended changes to all of 3 settings?

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't help. Still disconnections appear. Any other ideas?

Comment: Setting in the connectionOption the value: `transports: ["polling"]` did it for me. Hope it helps someone.